# MFC edit control strange behaviour

Tags: mfc

I ran into an awkward behaviour of CEdit when setting it's font: for a certain font size, letters like 'g' or 'j' have the bottom part missing, regardless of CEdit's rect height. Here are two examples:

```
CFont *ctrlFont = new CFont();
ctrlFont ->CreatePointFont(80, "Arial Black");

CEdit m_editName;
m_editName.SetFont(ctrlFont);
```

with this result:
[image]

but for

```
ctrlFont ->CreatePointFont(100, "Arial Black");
```

everything is fine
[image]

As you can observe, the CEdit's rect height is larger than the text's height in both cases. The parent control is a CDialog; the font is set on `::OnInitDialog` and CEdit's size is set with `SetWindowPos` method on `::OnShowWindow`. What could cause this, and how should i handle it?

Edit: i've tried @rrirower 's suggestion, and now i'm confussed; adding the CEdit's `CDC` to CFont's initialization changed the text's mask alot (you may not see it from the beggining, but i have other edit's with the old font on the same page and there's a big difference):

```
ctrlFont1->CreatePointFont(80, "Arial Black", m_editName.GetDC());
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried specifying a DC on the CreatePointFont call?  Not sure it will make a difference, but, worth the try.

Comment: @rrirower, i've tried your suggestion, but the results are somehow, weird: the text doesn't look like the last time. i'll update my question with this result.

Comment: @rrirower that implies the edit control DC has different characteristics than the desktop DC. How could that be?

Comment: @MarkRansom  Not sure.  But, if it didn't, why is it available as a passed parameter on the call?

Comment: @rrirower sometimes you need to create a font for a printer, for example.

Comment: How do you calculate CEdit's size based on the created font size? It appears that your CEdit is too short.

Answer (score 1):

Call CreateFont() with all parameters

```
 font.CreateFont(
   12,                        // nHeight
   0,                         // nWidth
   0,                         // nEscapement
   0,                         // nOrientation
   FW_NORMAL,                 // nWeight
   FALSE,                     // bItalic
   FALSE,                     // bUnderline
   0,                         // cStrikeOut
   ANSI_CHARSET,              // nCharSet
   OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // nOutPrecision
   CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,       // nClipPrecision
   DEFAULT_QUALITY,           // nQuality
   DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS,  // nPitchAndFamily
   _T("Arial")));                 // lpszFacename
```